# Getting sender in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large list of check boxes all with unique `id` values. I'd like to get the `id` of the checkbox that executes my JavaScript function. Can I do this using `$(this)`?

Comment: You'll need to provide your example first, of what you mean by "checkbox [...] executes my JavaScript function"

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can get the target of the event using [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

```
$('input:checkbox[id]').change(function(event) {
  var checkboxID = $(event.target).attr('id');
  alert(checkboxID);
});
```

[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VGGT8/)

Comment: In my case - with the button element on chrome and safari works only the version with $(this). So be careful with the usage of $(event.target)

Answer (score 18):

If `this` points to your checkbox, then you would get the id using `$(this).attr('id')`

For example:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    // do something with id
});
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j6TAf/).

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, sorry if I wasn't clear enough. :(

Comment: @esqew: See the demo in my answer.

Comment: This solution relies on `this` not being bounded to something else. `event.target` is a more stable solution.

Comment: @Andrew: In the event handlers in jQuery `this` **always** refers to the DOM element to which the handler is bound. See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#event-handlers). Also, the `event.target` can be the element to which the handler is bound or the **descendant** of that element, so they are not equivalent. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

Comment: @rsp: Because there are a lot of descendants to `<input>`.

Comment: @Andrew: You're right but checkboxes are not the only elements that can have event handlers. For example see [this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9zNGT/) - two paragraphs with click handlers that highlight them. The handler that uses `this` highlights the entire paragraph no matter where you click, but the handler that uses `event.target` sometimes highlights only a part of paragraph when you happen to click on a bold text. I have seen code like this in the wild and that's why I recommend using `this` as a general rule of thumb. But you're right that it doesn't matter for checkboxes of course.